# Is it possible to customize persistent to have the same field names for json and lenses?

Tags: json, haskell, persistent, haskell-lens

Given this:

```
import           Database.Persist.TH

share [mkPersist sqlSettings  { mpsGenerateLenses = True }] [persistLowerCase|
Book json
    title String
    pages Int
    deriving Eq Read Show Generic
|]
```

I get JSON like this:

```
{ "title": "Persistent book", "pages": 50 }
```

and I can use lenses like this:

```
book ^. bookTitle
```

Is it possible to tell `persistent` to automatically generate JSON like this:

```
{ "_bookTitle": "Persistent book", "_bookPages": 50 }
```

to match the model lenses?

Comment: There is no specific option for that (only for [the opposite move](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-7.19/persistent-template-2.5.1.6/Database-Persist-TH.html#v:mpsPrefixFields) i.e. removing the "book" prefix from the lenses), but it seems you can write custom `toJSON` and `fromJSON` functions that suit your purposes and use them instead of the default ones through the [`mpsEntityJSON` setting](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-7.19/persistent-template-2.5.1.6/Database-Persist-TH.html#v:mpsEntityJSON).